# readInt16() in c# vs readShort() in java

Tags: java, c#, binary, filereader, unsigned-integer

I am reading a binary file (that was written in c#) in java. its a long file more than 360Kb. I have to read the code byte by byte to populate the fields.
we have reading code already implemented in c# and have to replicate the behavior. In c# the code is something like this

```
FileVersion = s.ReadByte()
FileVersionMinor = s.ReadByte()
HeaderLength = s.ReadInt16()
```

Now I am trying to do same as above in java

```
dis = new DataInputStream(fin);
fileVersionMajor = dis.readUnsignedByte()
def fileVersionMinor = dis.readUnsignedByte()
def headerLength = dis.readShort()
```

but I get different output, when i tried to drill down the issue, I see that java code appends 00000000 at the end of streambyte.

Whats the issue here?

PS if I do 
`def headerLength = dis.readByte()`,
I get expected value.

Comment: There is no `def` keyword as C#'s `var` in Java, maybe you mean Scala (requires retag to [scala])?

Answer (score 0):

You probably  need to use `readByte()` instead of `readUnsignedByte()`.

Comment: you are wrong, ReadByte() gives the unsigned int so as readUnsignedByte()